# Laptop: self contained multimedia center

Tags: laptop

I'm choosing a laptop as a gift for a person who watches a lot of movies, browses internet and does some Excell or World processing. 
The strict requirements:

- 15.6 good LED backlit, matte screen
- at least 4 GB of ram
- good sound quality
- either no system at all (lower cost) or any Windows 10

Prefered:

- IPS screen
- Intel i3 or higher, 6 or 7 generation
- no dedicated video card (lower cost, and Intel HD is more than capable for multimedia)
- M.2 SSD + empty place for HDD or HDD mounted (any size)

Does not matter:

- DVD or lack thereof

The screen quality and audio quality are especially important, as there is no way for a person to plug external speakers or monitor. I am not sure if it's good idea to go Full HD, as the person is used to 1366 x 768 resolution, wears glasses and the videos watched are all in lower resolution. I am sure though, that IPS would be great, however I found it extremly hard to find in this resolution and under the budget of:

- budget: 820 $

I'm currently considering:

- Dell Vostro 5568
- Lenovo Ideapad 700-15
- HP ProBook 450 G3

but have no idea how they compare in sound quality (I know I know, they're laptops, but there is really no way for external speakers) and display quality. I will appreciate your help with choosing between the three or proposing something else within requirements. Thanks!